# MATLAB: Algebraic solution of an equation, comparing a coefficients method

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math

I have really big problem solving equations like this one (simplified one):

`a*cos(x) + b*sin(x) = cos(x) + sin(x)`, with respect to `a,b.`

In the equation can stand expressions of: `sin(x), cos(x), exp(C*x)` and polynomials.

I need to get solution in this form: `[a b] = [1 1].`

Only solution I can reach now is: `b = 0, a = (cos(x) + sin(x))/cos(x)`.

I was trying hard to find something, but I did not find anything. I really appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I get it. If I specify the variables with *assume*:

```
assume(a, 'real')

assume(b, 'real')
```

I get the result I am looking for.